# Munin stopped updating

Tags: centos, munin

today at 02:20 I noticed that suddenly Munin stopped updating its graphs. It is not showing blank data, the whole graphs are not being updated anymore.

I run CentOs 5.7 (64) and ive installed Munin via yum. All was working, till 02:20.

First thing I did was restart Munin: service munin-node restart.

It restarted without problems or errors, but it still didn't update the graphs.

So I checked out all the log files in: /var/log/munin and apart from munin-node.log non of the files were updated since 02:20.

All that was added to munin-node.log was:

> 2011/12/06-02:57:19 Server closing! Process Backgrounded
>   2011/12/06-02:57:20 Munin::Node::Server (type Net::Server::Fork)
>   starting! pid(16603) Using default listen value of 128 Binding to TCP
>   port 4949 on host 127.0.0.1 Setting gid to "0 0"

On every restart I tried after the same message showed up.

I am really clueless to why Munin stopped working all the sudden. Any idea what I can try?

Comment: Is the crontab file still there (`/etc/cron.d/munin`)?  Is cron still running?  What happens on that host when you do `telnet localhost 4949` and say `list`?  Could you update your question with some of this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the user which munin is running as has enough permisison to write to `.rrd`, `.png`, `.html` files. There is [a question](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/faq#Q.Thegraphsarenotupdatinganymore) on the Munin FAQ.

Comment: Ive removed all the .rrd files, and the .html files, restarted it again, and eventually it started working again.

Answer (score 5):

I once had this problem when one of my servers restarted, runing the command `munin-check` helped me realize the problem had to do with folder permissions.

Note: Even though I already had a folder `/var/www/html/munin/web/monitoring` and it has correct permissions set, `munin-check` complained about not finding that folder, I guess that's what the "this script may be buggy" warning means.

Comment: You can also run this with the option "--fix-permissions"